# MySQL: Inserting Value from Select Tag Becomes Truncated

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to insert a value into MySQL from HTML select tags:

```
<select name="venuesend">
    <option value="37">LATINO SPORTS CLUB</option>
    <option value="38">RED HOOK VISION CENTER</option>
    <option value="39">ANTHOLOGY FILM ARCHIVES</option>
    <option value="40">HUMMINGBIRD STUDIOS</option>
    <option value="41">THE PRODUCERS CLUB</option>
</select>
```

So, If `LATINO SPORTS CLUB` is selected, the value of `37` should be sent to MySQL. Currently, though, the value that is posted to MySQL is consistently `3`. So, I'm guessing this is being truncated for whatever reason.

Here is my PHP and HTML Form:

```
<?php

            //if "submit" is clicked
            if(isset($_POST['upload2'])) {


                //check if image files were uploaded
                foreach($_FILES['images']['error'] as $err){
                    switch ($err){
                        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                            echo 'No file sent.';
                            exit;
                    }
                }

                //iterate through each image file uploaded
                for($x=0; $x<count($_FILES['images']['tmp_name']); $x++){


                    //THIS IS WHERE VENUESEND IS POSTED

                    $screeningID2 = $_POST['venuesend'][$x];
                    $file_name = $_FILES['images']['name'][$x];
                    $file_tmp = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$x];

                    ....

                        //SQL statement and Posting
                        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO screeningImages (screeningId, imageURL) VALUES ('$screeningID2', '$file_name')";
                        mysqli_query($db, $sql2);
                    } else{
                        echo "Only images can be stored.";
                    }
                }
            }

        ?>  

        //HTML Form
        <form method="post" action="screenings-admin.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">


        //SELECT

        <select name="venuesend">
            <option value="37">LATINO SPORTS CLUB</option>
            <option value="38">RED HOOK VISION CENTER</option>
            <option value="39">ANTHOLOGY FILM ARCHIVES</option>
            <option value="40">HUMMINGBIRD STUDIOS</option>
            <option value="41">THE PRODUCERS CLUB</option>
        </select>


            //Images Upload
            <input type="file" id="imageUpload" name="images[]" multiple="" onchange="javascript:updateList()"/>

            //submit button
            <input type="submit" name="upload2" value="Upload" id="upload2">
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are attempting to access an array of a string (`37`), as you are calling `$screeningID2 = $_POST['venuesend'][$x];`.

`<select>` POSTs pass through the selected **value** with `$_POST[id]`; you don't actually need to reference `$x` at all, and simply need:

`$screeningID2 = $_POST['venuesend'];`

You're getting `3` coming through because `$_POST['venuesend']` is already the string `37`, and you are essentially taking the first **character** of the string.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Some part of the code in unclear, but this should solve the issue, from the looks of it.

```
$screeningID2 = $_POST['venuesend'][$x]
```

to

```
$screeningID2 = $_POST['venuesend];
```

With `[$x]` at the end, you are trying to store/read a character from the whole string stored in the variable. Try this code and update us back, so we can see if that fixes it.